# GData YouTube upload in background when app is applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube

i am using the GData and uploading movie to youtube in my app. my question is how can i upload the video when the app is Enter Background ( home button pressed ). i am dont know if it's relevant but i setShouldFetchInBackground = YES. thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using BackgroundTaskIdentifier

.h 
// Background Thread

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier btIdentifier;

.m
// Before starting your upload request 
//Background Thread - Start (for uploading)

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
{

    btIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endBackgroundTask:btIdentifier];
    }];
}
```

Once your upload has finished,
//Background thread stop

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:btIdentifier];
    btIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

This will allow you to continue to upload data when the app enters background. 
Hope it helps.